# Regex to find all the words with at least 3 specific characters

Tags: regex

I am solving a problem using regular expressions in which I need to find all the words in a sentence having at least 3 specific characters. Let's say I have following data:

Define a pattern for selecting all words containing at least three times the character `a` (including its uppercase variant `A`).

The example sentence for the test is:

```
Anastasia would like to have a banana split.
```

So what I have done is that I've compiled all the possible situations that I can face:

[image]

So far I have written a regular expression using pipes for the 4th and 6th situation and it works for the given text.

```
"\\b(\\b[Aa]{1}[^Aa\\W\\s]*[Aa]{1}[^Aa]*[Aa]{1,}\\w*\\b)|(\\b[^Aa\\W]*[Aa]{1}[^Aa\\W]*[Aa]{1}[^Aa\\W]*[Aa]{1,}\\w*\\b)"
```

- Am I doing it right?
- Is it efficient?
- Is there a concept in regular expressions that allow me to count for specific characters?
- I learnt in "Theory of Automata" that NFA/DFA are limited in a way that count can not be tracked. So do I have to use advanced turing machines?

Answer (score 1):

That looks quite convoluted. I think it would be quicker and easier to start at a word boundary, and repeat a group that contains (zero or more non-A, non-space characters, followed by a single A character) 3 times, followed by more characters until you get to the next space:

```
\b(?:[^a ]*a){3}\w*
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZVxATc/2

(of course, make sure to use the case-insensitive flag so you don't have to spell out things like `[aA]`)

Answer (score 0):

How about `/^([^a]*a){3}[^a]*$/`.

This will find exactly 3 `a` characters in a string.

This can be seen working **[here](https://regex101.com/r/ABX0nS/1/)**, and I add a few test strings in the following:

```js
const regex = /^([^a]*a){3}[^a]*$/;
const strings = ['abcabcabc', 'abcabc', 'abcabcabcabc', 'aaa', 'abab', 'ababa', 'a a a', 'a ba ba', 'a ab ab', 'a ab ab ab', 'b ab ab ab'];

for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  console.log(strings[i] + ": " + regex.test(strings[i]));
}
```

Comment: I thought the input was a sentence rather than individual words, in which case the `^`/`$` anchors will be problematic, and the two `[^a]`s will match space characters too. Also, I think OP is looking for "all the words with at least 3 specific characters", not "exactly 3" occurrences

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, that uses look ahead:

```
\b(?=([^ ]*a){3,})\w*\b
```

It starts at a `word boundary,` then creates a look ahead checking:

zero or more non Space chacacters followed by a `'a'`. It repeats this 3 or more times.

Then it matches zero or more Word characters and finally a Word boundary.

You should use the 'IgnoreCase' flag.

**Examples of match:**

abcabcabc banana aaa aaabbaa

```js
const regex = /\b(?=([^ ]*a){3,})\w*\b/;
const strings = ['abcabcabc', 'abcabc', 'abcabcabcabc', 'aaa', 'abab', 'ababa', 'a a a', 'a ba ba', 'a ab ab', 'a ab ab ab', 'b ab ab ab'];

for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  console.log(strings[i] + ": " + regex.test(strings[i]));
}
```